# How to keep dynamically generated HTML upon validation failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, validation

I have a page with various input field. Some additional fields can be added and they are generated with Javascript. The issue I am having is that upon validation failure the page is reloaded and the generated content input fields are lost. How would I go about it to preserve these input fields? Thanks

Comment: Validate the form on the client side, without reloading.

Comment: Consider submitting via AJAX instead of a standard form POST.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use local storage or cookies to store what are the input fields which were added to the page? so that when the page is reloaded it can repopulate that information?

More about [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

More about [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I see the laravel tag but I do not know if you use laravel, for those who use laravel, you can retrieve the form data after server-side validation as below:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
```

Comment: What I am looking for is not how to get old data, but rather how to keep the generated html after POSTing.

Comment: Sorry I misread the problem, I can delete the answer if you wish !